# Solve integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}(x^2+x+1)}dx$ using substitution $x=\sinh t$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

How to solve the definite Integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}\ (x^2+x+1)}dx=\frac{\ln(2+\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}}$$
with the hyperbolic function $x=\sinh t$?

Below is using the usual substitution $x=\tan t$ to do it. I thought it is the same because $\sinh^2t+1=\cosh^2t$ is similar with $\tan^2t+1=\sec^2t$. But, It isn't...

> Substituting $$x=\tan t, dt=\sec^2{t} \ dx ,(0\leq t\leq\pi/2)$$
> So, we get
> $$
> \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}(x^2+x+1)}dx =\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec{t}}{1+\tan{t}+\tan^2{t}}dt \\=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos{t}}{1+\sin{t}\cos{t}}dt\\=I
> $$
> Note that $\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)}=\sin{t}$, hence substituting $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$, we have
> $\cos{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t\right)}=\sin{t}$, hence substituting $t=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$, we have
> $$
> \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos{t}}{1+\sin{t}\cos{t}}dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{1+\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}d\theta=I
> $$
> Therefore, by substitution $ \sin{t}-\cos{t}=\xi, (\sin{t}+\cos{t})dt=d\xi $
> $$
> 2I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos{t}+\sin{t}}{1+\sin{t}\cos{t}}dt\\=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-\xi^2}{2}}d\xi \\=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{3-\xi^2}d\xi \\=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt3-\xi}+\frac{1}{\sqrt3+\xi}d\xi \\=\frac{1}{ \sqrt3 }\left(\ln(\sqrt3-\xi)-\ln(\sqrt3+\xi) \bigg\rvert_{-1}^{1}\right)\\=\frac{2\ln(2+\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt3}
> $$
> Because of the result, given integral is
> $$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}(x^2+x+1)}dx=\frac{\ln(2+\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}}$$

What is actually different with this using the substitution $x=\sinh t$ instead?

Comment: Why don't you use the Euler substitution?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I don't know Euler substitution alot...., I'll try using it too!! But I'm curious about using hyperbolic function because i'm stuck with it...

Answer (score 4):

It is another route to reach the same result, as shown below
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}\ (x^2+x+1)}\overset{x\to 1/x}{dx}\\
=&\ \frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}\ (x^2+x+1)} \overset{x=\sinh t}{dx}\\
=& \ \frac12\int_0^\infty \frac{1+\sinh t}{\cosh^2 t+\sinh t}dt
= \frac12 \int_0^\infty 
\frac{\text{sech}\,t(\text{sech}\,t +\tanh t)}{1+\text{sech}\,t\tanh t}dt\\
=& \int_0^\infty \frac{d(\tanh t- \text{sech}\,t )}{3-(\tanh t- \text{sech}\,t)^2}= \frac{\ln(2+\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Letting $x=\tan \theta$ yields
$$
I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}\left(x^2+x+1\right)} d x
= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\cos \theta}{1+\sin \theta \cos \theta} d \theta
$$
Multiplying both numerator and denominator by $1-\sin \theta \cos \theta$ yields
$$
I=\int_0^1 \frac{d s}{1-s^2\left(1-s^2\right)}-\int_0^1 \frac{c^2 d c}{1-\left(1-c^2\right) c^2}
$$
Since $s=\sin \theta$ and $c=\cos \theta$ are dummy, we can rewrite $I$ as
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^1 \frac{1-t^2}{t^4-t^2+1} d t \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{\frac{1}{t^2}-1}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}-1} d t \\
& = -\int_0^1 \frac{d\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-3} \\
& = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}} \ln \left|\frac{t+\frac{1}{t}+\sqrt{3}}{t+\frac{1}{t}-\sqrt{3}}\right|_0^1\\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \ln (2+\sqrt{3})
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $$\sqrt{x^2+1}=x+t$$ we get $$x=\frac{1-t^2}{2t}$$ so $$dx=-\frac{t^2+1}{2 t^2}dt$$
and $$\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{1+t^2}{2t}$$

Comment: This is about euler substitution? It's cool!!

Comment: Yes, i have seen the question.

Comment: so given integral changes $\int_{0}^{\infty}dx \to \int_{-1}^{-\infty}dt$???

Comment: Compute at first the indefinite integral

Comment: But it isn't hard to compute indefinite integral? I get it but it is too coplicate to calculate....

Comment: So.... Euler substitution can only applied into indefinite integral?

Comment: No, but the integral will be simpler.

Comment: $-\dfrac{\ln\left(\left(t-1\right)\left(t+\sqrt{3}\right)+2\right)-\ln\left(\left(t-1\right)\left(t-\sqrt{3}\right)+2\right)}{2\sqrt{3}}+\arctan\left(\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right)t+1\right)-\arctan\left(\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right)t-1\right)$ this is indefinite integral by substitution.... I think it is too hard to do it....

Comment: If you are okay, than would you show how to use euler substitution to this problem??? I have no idea how to do it....

Answer (score 0):

First simplify the integrand by substituting $x=\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}$:

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1} \left(x^2+x+1\right)} \, dx \\
&= \sqrt2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{1+y}{\sqrt{1+y^2} \left(3+y^2\right)} \, dy \\
&= \sqrt2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^2} \left(3+y^2\right)}
\end{align*}$$

Proceeding with the suggested substitution $y=\sinh t$, we have

$$\newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}
I = \sqrt2 \int_{-\sinh^{-1}1}^{\sinh^{-1}1} \frac{dt}{3+\sinh^2t} \cdot \frac{\sech^2t}{\sech^2t} = \sqrt2 \int_{-\sinh^{-1}1}^{\sinh^{-1}1} \frac{d\tanh t}{3-2\tanh^2t} \, dt$$

which can be further wrapped up with $u=\tanh t$,

$$I = \sqrt2 \int_{-\tfrac1{\sqrt2}}^{\tfrac1{\sqrt2}} \frac{du}{3-2u^2} = \boxed{\frac{\log\left(2+\sqrt3\right)}{\sqrt3}}$$